# Trouble with WebSocket (wss) Connection Using Socket.IO in Laravel, Node.js (Redis + Socket.io), and Angular

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on this project where I've got Laravel in the backend, Node.js with Redis and Socket.IO for websocket, and Angular in the frontend. Everything is working fine in my local environment but problem is occuring in my live staging server. HTTPS pre-requests of Socket.IO for websocket connection are working fine, but I'm stuck with WebSocket (wss) connections. When wss tries to connect to server it get `Finished` quickly instead of going in 101 status mode.

**Error**

- Error i get in console log is
  `WebSocket connection failed`

**Background:**

- Backend: Laravel
- Real-time Server: Node.js + Redis + Socket.IO
- Frontend: Angular

**Server**

```
// import { config } from "dotenv";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import fs from 'fs';
dotenv.config();
const SOCKET_PORT = process.env.SOCKET_PORT || 9000;
const SOCKET_HOST = process.env.SOCKET_HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const REDIS = {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || "127.0.0.1",
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || "6379",
};
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./storage/logs/socket-log.txt'));
myConsole.log('Socket.io Logs');

function handler(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    if (request.url == '/log') {
        fs.readFile('./socket-log.txt', null, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Whoops! File not found!');
            } else {
                response.write(data);
            }
            response.end();
        });
        response.end(); //end the response
    }
    fs.readFile('./socket-server.html', null, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import ioRedis from "ioredis";

// Create http server
var app = new createServer(handler);
// Create socket.io server
var io = new Server(app, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});
// Create redis server
var redis = new ioRedis(REDIS);
// Duplicate redis server for publishing
var pubRedis = redis.duplicate();

// Listent http server on socket port
const listener = app.listen(SOCKET_PORT, SOCKET_HOST, function() {
    console.log(
        new Date() +
        " - Server is running on port " +
        SOCKET_PORT +
        " and listening Redis on port " +
        REDIS.port +
        "!"
    );
    console.log(listener.address().port);
});
io.engine.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(err.req); // the request object
    console.log(err.code); // the error code, for example 1
    console.log(err.message); // the error message, for example "Session ID unknown"
    console.log(err.context); // some additional error context
    myConsole.log(err.req); // the request object
    myConsole.log(err.code); // the error code, for example 1
    myConsole.log(err.message); // the error message, for example "Session ID unknown"
    myConsole.log(err.context); // some additional error context
});
// Establish connection with clients
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log('A client connected : ' + socket.id);
    myConsole.log('A client connected : ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
        myConsole.error('Error: ', error);
    });
    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error: ', error);
        myConsole.error('Error: ', error);
        // Log the communication error or take necessary actions.
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", function(reason) {
        console.log("A client disconnected: " + socket.id + ", Reason: " + reason);
        myConsole.log("A client disconnected: " + socket.id + ", Reason: " + reason);
    });
});
io.on("disconnect", function(socket) {
    console.log('A client disconnected : ' + socket.id);
    myConsole.log('A client disconnected : ' + socket.id);
});
// Ready to connect
io.on("connect", function(socket) {
    console.log("A connect");
    myConsole.log("A connect");
});
// Subscribe to Redis Server
redis.psubscribe("*", function(err, count) {
    console.log("Subscribed to Redis Server");
    myConsole.log("Subscribed to Redis Server");
});
// Listen to Broadcasted Channels on Redis Server
redis.on("pmessage", function(subscribed, channel, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    console.log(new Date() + " => " + "\nChannel: " + channel + ", \nData: ", data.data);
    var res = io.emit(channel, data.data);
    console.log("Broadcasted to " + channel + ": " + (res ? "Success" : "Failure"));
    console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    myConsole.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    myConsole.log(new Date() + " => " + "\nChannel: " + channel + ", \nData: ", data.data);
    myConsole.log("Broadcasted to " + channel + ": " + (res ? "Success" : "Failure"));
    myConsole.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
});
```

**Client**

```
const SOCKET_PORT = 9000;
    socket = io(`https://learn-socket.weboccult.com`);
    // client-side
    socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
    });
    socket.on("connect", (socket) => {
        node = "<p>Socket Connected to Server </p>"
        document.querySelector('#logs').innerHTML = node
    });
    socket.on('admin:notifications', (data) => {
        node = "<p>Last Broadcast Done At : " + new Date() + "</p>";
        document.querySelector('#broadcast').innerHTML = node
    });
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        node = "<p>Socket Disconnected</p>"
        document.querySelector('#logs').innerHTML = node
    });
```

I have tried every possible troubleshooting mentioned in socket.io documentaion but i can't find what's the issue.